# mysql server date difference

Tags: mysql, date

Hi I have a problem with my script and server:

I need to make query from last 3 minutes.

here is my current query:

```
SELECT *, now() as date FROM data WHERE created > date_sub( NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MINUTE) LIMIT 0,100
```

I got this:

```
+----------------------------+---------------------+
| ID |       created         |         date        |
+----+-------+---------------+---------------------+
| 1  |  2012-05-10 14:14:33  | 2012-05-10 16:14:38 |
+----+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

please note the 2 more hours on date row.

How I can tell mysql about these difference?

Comment: What does `SELECT NOW(), DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)` tell you?

Comment: 2012-05-10 16:30:00 | 2012-05-10 16:27:00 the 3 minutes is ok but my script set to a new timezone and then save it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly doubt that this is a MySQL problem, because it doesn't store time zones inside your date fields.

Seems like this problem lies somewhere else down the processing pipe line.